# KineticJS - How to find out which object were dragged?

Tags: object, canvas, drag, kineticjs

is there some possibility, how to realise, which object were moved? If I had for example 5 object on canvase and I would move one object, is there any information about what changed since any time? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Attach dragend handler function, which event variable has targetNode, which is the node that the drag event has happened on.

```
node.on('dragend', function (event) { console.log('dragged node: ' + event.targetNode); }
```